# Best practice webservice client singleton

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy, singleton, client

I am implementing a web application which uses a webservice to retrieve data. What is best practice;

- Create the webservice proxy as a singleton once and use this for all
  calls
- Every time a webservice call is done, create the proxy with `using(var p = new Proxy())`

I notice when using the second option, every first call takes +- 500ms and next calls using this client take +- 180ms.

Comment: I would say proxy as a singleton is better like create the proxy every time call is done.

Comment: Are there any reasons why you should not use a singleton proxy?

Comment: Scalability; A singleton maintains state which could cause scalability issues, a per call does not. Access management; A singleton proxy could cause problems when used in a multithreaded environment, a per call does not.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefere 2nd case:

```
using(var p = new Proxy())
```

- There is no memory leaks outside of using. The object is destructed
- Better support for exception handling
- You may use it async.
- You may pack it in a lib and use as a reference in several projects,
  or use    in derived class, with no fear that something can be broken
  in your single forever instance.

Comment: But what about performance? Creating a new Proxy for every call with the using statement, makes the call 300ms longer.

Comment: Well, I guess that 300ms is just after build, or this 300ms gap is always happening, and CLR does not optimize these calls? Anyway, it is depends on your usage the proxy. If you use it, say, in a loop, then you should use an instance. If you use it time to time, handling some rare user request, then I wouldn't care about 300ms.  Anyway, I recomend you to implement a stress test and see how your code feels under a stress. If 300ms gap will not affect the result, then use using.